# CRC16-CCITT Incorrect result?

Tags: c, crc16

I am making a program which will communicate with a bootloader to update the firmware of a microcontroller. Everything is ready except the `CRC calculation`.

I have used CRC calculation function from [here](http://stjarnhimlen.se/snippets/crc-16.c) to calculate CRC16 for polynomial `x16 + x12 + x5 + 1` (0b10001000000100001).

But the result for input `0x3304000012345678` is coming out to be wrong. I have checked over this [website](https://www.ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=10001000000100001&Message=3304000012345678). Also, i have double checked with a python script which i am replicating in `C`. The python script calculates the `CRC` correctly.

Here is the code from the website:

```
uint16_t crc16(uint8_t *data_p, unsigned length)
{
  unsigned char i;
  unsigned int data;
  unsigned int crc = 0xffff;

  if (length == 0)
        return (~crc);

  do
  {
        for (i=0, data=(unsigned int)0xff & *data_p++;
             i < 8; 
             i++, data >>= 1)
        {
              if ((crc & 0x0001) ^ (data & 0x0001))
                    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ POLY;
              else  crc >>= 1;
        }
  } while (--length);

  crc = ~crc;
  data = crc;
  crc = (crc << 8) | (data >> 8 & 0xff);

  return (crc);
}
```

Comment: I would blame endianness.

Comment: I am passing `uint8_t` array. I guess endianess shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How do you know the website is using CRC16-CCITT?

Comment: I have supplied by polynomial and input data in that website. Also, a python scripts also calculates it correctly.

Comment: What do you refer by "correctly"? The one from the website? Can you provide the values in the question along with the python script? The same polynomial might be used by different CRC algorithms.

Comment: The algorithm above seems to be shifting values to the right instead of the left. When it is done, it swaps the low 8 bits with the high 8 bits, but they're still in the wrong order.

Comment: That's what i thought in the beginning and tried few modifications but i didn't get correct result

Comment: Where is this python script that is "correct"? What is the expected CRC of the example input in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've compared the C code you posted with the algorithm at the web site you linked, and I've found two main differences:

1) The C code you posted processes the bits in the reverse order of the web site. This is true for both the CRC calculation itself (shifts right, where the web site shifts left), and for the processing of each byte of input (processes the least significant bit first, where the web site processes the most significant bit first).

2) The C code inverts all the bits in the CRC value before returning it, and also swaps the low and high bytes. The web site's algorithm includes no such post-processing.

I've updated the C code you pasted to match the web site:

```
uint16_t crc16(const uint8_t *data_p, unsigned length)
{
  unsigned char i;
  uint8_t data;
  unsigned int crc = 0; // 0xffff;

  while (length-- > 0)
  {
    for (i = 0, data = *data_p++; 
         i < 8;
         i++, data <<= 1)
    {
      if ((crc >> 15) ^ (data >> 7))
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ POLY;
      else
        crc <<= 1;

      crc &= 0xffff;
    }
  }

  return crc;
}
```

The differences:

1) The `data` local variable is now of type `uint8_t`.

2) The `crc` variable is initialized to 0 instead of 0xFFFF, as suggested by @AShelly. The web site specifically mentions that it initializes all the registers to 0 before beginning the calculation.

3) Rather than separately testing for length 0, I've restructured the loop from a 'do' loop to a 'while' loop, so that it simply doesn't enter the loop in the first place if 'length' is 0.

4) In the `for` loop, `data` is shifted left instead of right. This is because we want to process its *high* bit first, then the bit to the right of that, and so on -- the left shift moves each subsequent bit into the high bit position.

5) The `if` statement that combines the carry with the new bit of input is now comparing the high bit of the CRC (`crc >> 15`) with the high bit of the data (`data >> 7`), instead of the low bit of each. The rest of the code ensures that `crc` won't have a bit in the 16th position, and `data` won't have a bit in the 8th position, so these shifts are guaranteed to yield a single bit only.

6) The actual `crc` calculation shifts to the left instead of the right.

7) After shifting `crc` to the left, I mask off any bits from position 16 on. This is the part of the code mentioned in point 4 that makes sure that `crc >> 15` yields only a single bit. (This could also be done by making `crc` be of type `uint16_t`.)

8) The post-processing code is removed. The final `crc` value is returned as it is when the loop completes.

With these changes, the CRCs produced by the C function match the web site.

Comment: Nice answer, but missed an opportunity to use the "downto" operator: `while (length --> 0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works as expected. I also tried to match to what that website has implemented but i guess i missed few things. Great answer. Deserves a million upvotes

Answer (score 1):

CRC-16 is not a unique spec, it depends on initializer and polynomial.  I'd suspect the `0xFFFF`
The website you are using uses `0x0000` as the initializer.

In a past job we used [this website](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) to verify implementations, after first verifying the website results for several known inputs.

Comment: Yes, i have looked at their algorithm and tried to use 0x0000 initializer in my program but it didn't help